# Extending bootstrap dropdown to bottom of visible page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown on my website that I would like to stretch to the visible bottom of my webpage. This is so I don't have to set a max-height on all the dropdowns when they can actually be stretched further to give the user more room to select their option. A 100% height will not work on this.

So, my html is pretty basic. It's just a bootstrap dropdown

```
<div class="dropdownscroll dropdown-menu side-dropdown>
  <div  class="mCustomScrollBox">
    <div id="mCSB_18_container" class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y">

        <ul>
            <li role="presentation">&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default dropdownBtn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">D</a></li>

            <li role="presentation">&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default dropdownBtn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">Married</a></li>

            <li role="presentation">&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default dropdownBtn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">Single</a></li>

            <li role="presentation">&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default dropdownBtn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">U</a></li>

            <li role="presentation">&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default dropdownBtn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">W</a></li>

            <li role="presentation">&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-default dropdownBtn" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-bind="html: Name">X</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried a few things, but it seems everything I do extends way below the visible part of the page...like by 600px.

I've tried

```
var theDiv = $('.dropdown-menu');
var divTop = theDiv.offset().top;
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var divHeight = winHeight - divTop;
theDiv.height(divHeight);
```

and

```
$('.dropdown-menu').height(function(index, height) {
    return window.innerHeight - $(this).offset().top;
});
```

and a few variations of

```
$('.dropdownscroll').height(function(index, height) {
    var current_height = $(this).height();
    var new_height = window.innerHeight - $(this).offset().top - parseInt($(this).css('padding-top')) - parseInt($(this).css('padding-bottom'));
        if (new_height > current_height) return new_height;
});
```

Any help would be amazing.

and a fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/rtr4kd2d/2/

Again, I cannot have the dropdown extend beyond the end of the page.

Comment: It seems like you have quite a lot lof custom classes and markup. Have you tried to achieve your goal with the clean bootstrap DEMO?

Comment: Also, please create a JSFiddle or something where your problem can be reproduced easily. It's hard without your actual class definitions.

Comment: Have you seen the scrollable dropdown menu demo for boot strap here? https://ugate.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/scrollable-twitter-bootstrap-menus/  He also has a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/XKEmy/

Comment: @ZoltánTamási, the html is as clean as you can get. The added classes are there just because of a scrollbar and I did not want to remove them. Here is a fiddle, but it is basically exactly what I have put here... http://jsfiddle.net/rtr4kd2d/

Comment: @crazymatt, I have to use a plugin for the scrollbar so all the scrollbars look the same on my page. My scroll works fine. Also, I cannot let the dropdown go past the bottom of the page, that is the issue here. I have an overflow hidden on the page and they would not be able to see all their options. Also, that fiddle did not want to work for me.

Comment: I think you should have a look on `bootstrap-select` library http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: @JhKaiz, why would I use that over the default bootstrap dropdown? Would that solve this issue without the javascript code?

Comment: @zazvorniki , at first, as you know that bootstrap doesn't apply dropdown, their dropdownlist is transform to `<div>` or `<ul><li>` items, and I always go to find any alternative dropdown for it, and bootstrap-select works well with me. If the dropdown was set at the bottom, it'll display to the top instead of bottom of `select` box.

Comment: @JhKaiz, You can do the same with a plain bootstap dropdown as well though, I have in the past. All, I'm really seeing in difference is a different syntax. My issue was not that I wanted the dropdown to 'drop up', but I needed it to extend to the bottom of the page, but not go past the visible bottom so it can support many items and be usable by a touchscreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the following code to the correct element (i am not sure if is .dropdown-menu, ):

```
var theDiv = $('.dropdown-menu'); 
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var divHeight = winHeight - $('#dropdownMenu1').offset().top - $('#dropdownMenu1').outerHeight()-2 ;
theDiv.css('height',divHeight);
```

divHeight is equal to screen height less the position of your dropdownMenu less his height and -2 (dropdown-menu has a little margin that push down the all dropdown)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. It's still adding an extra 300px to the div and reaching way below where the page ends.

Comment: I guess, my issue is that it is calculating too much of a height and adding it instead of too little.

Comment: I'm still getting the same results. It's still calculating the heights wrong. It's still stretching way below the bottom of the page, it's now saying the height it 836px. Is there anyway to calculate the height below the div instead of above it? I don't really think the margin has anything to do with it, this is not a small amount, this is projecting more than 400px. And I would really like to try and solve this without putting the specific elements into the calculation because it is a dynamic page and they won't always be named the same or have the same classes...

Comment: Because that's how it's actually going to appear on the page and if it doesn't work with other elements on the page then it's not working... And the dropdown does not just appear at the bottom of the inputs, it can appear in many other places on the page. Hence why I need it to calculate what space is left at the bottom of the page, not the top because I have no idea where it's going to be placed.

Comment: @zazvorniki Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rtr4kd2d/4/ It is not depends of the elements above the element

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I worked with this so much that my brain was turning to mush! You saved me and my brain! :)